# Nullpointerexception EasyMock when testing Controller

Tags: java, unit-testing, easymock

I want to test my controller class and its methods.

My Controller method looks like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/updateUserStory/{usid}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String updateUserStory(@PathVariable("trrid") Integer trrID, @PathVariable("usid") Integer userstoryID, Model model ){
    UserStory userStory = this.userStoryService.getUserStoryById(userstoryID);

    model.addAttribute("userstory", userStory);
    model.addAttribute("trrID", trrID);

    return "updateUserStory";
}
```

My test method looks like this:

```
public void updateUserStory() throws Exception {
    Model model = mockModel();

    UserStory userStory = new UserStory();
    userStory.setId(1);

    EasyMock.expect(userStoryService.getUserStoryById(1)).andReturn(userStory);
    EasyMock.replay(userStoryService);

    String test = controller.updateUserStory(1, 1, model );

    EasyMock.verify(userStoryService);

    Assert.assertEquals("updateUserStory", test);
}
```

I added `@Mock` above for the `userStoryService`

```
@Mock
private UserStoryServiceImpl userStoryService;
```

and `@TestSubject` for the `UserStoryController` (In the test simply called controller).

```
@TestSubject
UserStoryController controller = new UserStoryController();
```

When running the test I keep getting A `NullPointerException` at the `EasyMock.expect` line. I don't know how this is failing. I am mocking the right method.

Comment: How does `userStoryService` get initialized?

Comment: @NimrodArgov Added that part

Comment: How will the controller class get access to `userStoryService`? Do you pass it in? Where is `controller` created?

Comment: From my understanding when you @Mock a class EasyMock wil automatically Mock the call coming from that class

Comment: Does your controller class have a setter for `UserStoryServiceImpl`?

Comment: Yes in my Controller class i have @Autowired private UserStoryServiceImpl userStoryService;

Answer (score 0):

I see two possible reasons.

**1. You haven't used any runner or rule.**

To inject mocks, EasyMock needs a JUnit rule

```
@Rule
public EasyMockRule mocks = new EasyMockRule(this);
```

or a runner

```
@RunWith(EasyMockRunner.class)
public class MyTest {
```

**2. The field type is `UserStoryService`**

Not `UserStoryServiceImpl`. So you should mock `UserStoryService` instead.